# Сформировать массив Y, включив в него все неповторяющиеся элементы из массива X

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Надо сформировать массив Y, включив в него все не повторяющиеся элементы из массива X.

```
void Mass::non_repeatable() {
int v = {1,2,3,4,5,4,6,1,2,7};
int dim = 10;
int length = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
        if (v[i] != v[j] && i != j) { //Здесь я хочу посчитать размер второго массива, в который я буду переносить не повторяющиеся элементы, но он считает не правильно и выводит полный размер массива.
            length++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cout << "\nLength=" << length; // проверка подсчета
int *copyArray = new int[length];
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
        if (v[i] != v[j] && i != j) 
            for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) { // в итоге он не правильно копирует элементы
                copyArray[k] = v[i];

            }

    }
}
for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << copyArray[k] << " ";
}
delete[] copyArray;
```

Comment: следует указать, что Вас не устраивает в приведенном коде, добавить пример входных данных, ожидаемый и получаемый результаты

Comment: Как входные данные у меня массив заполненный случайными числами, а не устраивает меня то, что он не правильно считает размер нового массива без повторяющихся элементов и то, что записывает в массив все подряд элементы

Comment: То есть Вы хотите, чтобы я придумывал данные сам? Я сейчас огорчусь и поставлю Вам минус (.

Comment: Исправил недочет

Comment: Очень хорошо. Вам понятно из моего ответа, где была ошибка?

Comment: Ну, когда я проверял почему считает все подряд, я понял, что при прохождении оно сравнивает каждый второй элемент с начала и находило , что они разные. Не могли бы вы чуть подробней объяснить алгоритм? Я понял, что мы, взводя флаг обозначаем одинаковые элементы и если они не одинаковы, то наращиваем. А если переписывать не повторяющиеся элементы в другой массив, то как мне получить позицию элемента, который нужно передать?

Comment: Я попросил Вас указать ожидаемый результат, но до сих пор его не вижу.

Comment: Да, алгоритм я понял

Comment: Кстати, если уж вы в этой задачке  быстро удаляете `copyArray[]`, то нет смысла определять количество уникальных элементов перед его созданием. Создавайте сразу размером `dim` и в тех же вложенных циклах, где сейчас ищете дубликаты, сразу заполняйте копию уникальными значениями. При этом лучше искать их не в исходном, а в строящемся массиве. Это будет быстрее. Не думаю, что вам стоит беспокоиться о перерасходе памяти. Если ее будет надо действительно много, то и квадратичный по времени алгоритм поиска дубликатов для решения задачи все равно не годится

Comment: @avp а-а-а, в этом и дело. В моем коде повторяющиеся значения в результат вообще не вообще не попадают, даже в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: @Igor, а-а-а-а..., теперь понял, что я не так прочел "ТЗ" -)

Answer (score 0):

используйте `std::vector` тогда вам не придётся определять размер в результирующем массиве (векторе). Он это сделает за вас:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7};
    std::vector<int> result;
    size_t size = v.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        bool isUnique = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            if (i != j && v[i] == v[j])
            {
                isUnique = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isUnique) result.push_back(v[i]);
    }

    for (const auto& i: result)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я на 2 курсе универа, мы этот метод не изучали, поэтому я не могу применить его